# Filter in DynamoDB by non PartitionKey and non sort key error - Query condition missed key schema element

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to filter results inside DynamoDB by data that is not PartitionKey or Sort KEY (name = RowKey).
I can limit the result by PartitionKey.
So I tried it in according to the documentation to make a query (without Sort Key) but I get this error:

```
  Unable to query. Error: {
  "message": "Query condition missed key schema element: RowKey",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2020-04-03T13:09:17.635Z",
  "requestId": "ECD4VQBGFB0IUM6G9TUSPKA3LRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 43.542922337630074
}
```

The following image is the configuration of the table

[image: Table configuration Keys and Sort]

And this is the code that I used:

```
    async function FilterUsersAwsQUERY (_tenant_id,_filter) {
    //debug('Enter in function');
    var params = {
      TableName : "zzzuser",
      ProjectionExpression:"#pk, comapnyrole",
      KeyConditionExpression: "#pk = :pk and #cr = :cr",
      ExpressionAttributeNames:{
          "#pk": "PartitionKey",
          "#cr": "companyrole"
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":pk":  _tenant_id,
          ":cr": _filter
      }

  };
    return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {

        //debug('Start query');
        docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                reject(err);
            } else {
                //console.log("AWS ALL Query succeeded.");
                resolve(data.Items);
                //data.Items.forEach(function(item) {
                //    console.log(" -", item.year + ": " + item.title);
                //});
            }
        });
    });
  };
```

PS. I know that there is a .scan options but it takes over 10 seconds to do it because I have 10.000 records inside it and every PartitionKey is about 400 records.

There is any way to do it efficently?
Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

The key condition expression has to be the partition key or the partition key and sort key. Then you can narrow it down with a [FilterExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression). That said, refining with a filter expression can be expensive if you have to do it often AND the result set to filter is large.

This is a time where a LSI or GSI might be a better bet if this is an access pattern you have to do often and with high performance. if it is not something you do often, it might be cheaper just to take the hit with the FilterExpression as that would be cheaper. You have not given enough info for me to know one way or the other.